# GDI+ DrawImage won't display

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, gdi+

I'm attempting to display a PNG file in a Visual C++ application. I've been trying a variety of methods over the past six or eight hours and need some help at this point. I've adapted the following lines from several tutorials. Why isn't the image displaying?

```
Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);
Gdiplus::Image * image = Gdiplus::Image::FromFile(L"C:\\test.png");       
graphics.DrawImage(image,0,0);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Or, if there's a better recommended way to display a PNG file, that would be great as well!

Comment: Where are you doing this? Where does `hdc` come from?

Comment: Have you checked that the image file loaded correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk of stating the blindingly obvious, have you initialised GDI+ with :

```
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
```

Other than that, as others have said - where is hdc coming from and is the image created successfully?

Comment: Oops - didn't realize that that was necessary, so thanks for stating the blindingly obvious :)  The only problem that remains is that the image doesn't persist on the window. It repaints itself when the window is resized, but then quickly disappears. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Either the image you've loaded going out of scope, or DrawImage() isn't in your OnPaint()/OnDraw()?